# Is this the correct way for only allowing logins via Devise + Omniauth in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I wanted to allow users to signup + login to a Rails app via omniauth only, no email / password sign up / login should be allowed  So I looked [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596918/configuring-routes-in-devise-when-only-using-omniauth-for-authentication), but that didn't work.  So I ended up generating customized views for registrations and sessions and commenting out email/password fields in the login + signup forms.

Then in config/initializers/devise.rb I set:

```
  config.params_authenticatable = false
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there isn't a very "clean" way to do this, because Devise is a very complete solution.
Please take a look here: [**Using only omniauth (twitter) sign-in with Devise, Rails 3, Omniauth**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949924/using-only-omniauth-twitter-sign-in-with-devise-rails-3-omniauth)

IMO, if you need just oauth authentication, maybe devise is too much for this. This Railscast may help you as well: [**Simple OmniAuth**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth)